# start wso2is-5.2 as window service

Tags: windows-services, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using `wso2is-5.2` as a identity server in my application. I have password encryption enabled in `wso2is`. At the time of making up `wso2is` from command prompt, it ask `"KeyStore and Private Key Password"` which is `wso2carbon` and I am able to pass this password and make `wso2is` up.

I want to create window service for `wso2is` and start & stop `wso2is` from service only, but I am not able to find the way of providing `"KeyStore and Private Key Password"`, when I will start `wso2is` as a service.

Please let me know any specific document related to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a windows service for WSO2IS 5.2.0 as described in [1] using yajsw.

You can resolve resolve the keystore password as described in [2]. So basically you can have a file with keystore password in product home directory. File name either can be named as password-tmp.txt or password-persist.txt. If you have the password-tmp.txt file, it will be deleted at the server startup and if you have password-persist.txt it will kept after server startup.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Resolving+Encrypted+Passwords